# while i try "apt-get install libcunit1=2.1-3-dfsg-2build1 libcunit1-dev"on Ubuntu Server 23.04，it faile!All environments are default

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

While i try "apt-get install libcunit1=2.1-3-dfsg-2build1 libcunit1-dev"on Ubuntu Server 23.04，it failed!

All environments are default

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcunit1-dev : Depends: libcunit1 (= 2.1-3-dfsg-2build1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Unable to locate package libjson-c3
```

Comment: The package available for *lunar* or 23.04 is `libcunit1 | 2.1-3-dfsg-2.4     | lunar/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which is the version required by the package you mention (https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libcunit1-dev) so your problem is likely a 3rd party source of which you gave no specifics.

Comment: Did you update before you install?

Comment: @guiverc, you are right. This is the issue I encountered while trying to build the kernel and installing some prerequisite libraries befor that. I opened the source code of the script, and it doesn't provide any specific version or environment requirements. Here is the script I'm providing, hoping it can give you some insights for problem-solving.
#meson
apt-get install -y libiniparser1 libiniparser-dev libkmod-dev ibkeyutils-dev
apt-get install -y libjson-c3 libjson-c-dev libudev1 libudev-dev ninja-build meson.

Comment: This is a Q&A site and not a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ being the address of Ubuntu Forums). If you have details you want people to read, please edit your question and add them there (*easier to read etc & greater editing options; we can help you with edits if required too*)  Providing details of where the script was from is also helpful (*the `-y` I see makes me nervous; as it requires assumptions that were probably documented where the script was from!*)   You can always start another question, but be specific & clear with what you've done & give all details.

Comment: thank you@guiverc,i'll post my question in other forum.I will also learn how to edit my questions to make them more beautiful and easier to read.

Comment: Can you recommend some websites to me? I am not sure where I can go to better consult and solve my problems.

Comment: This site is fine; my point was this is a Q&A site and not a forum (ie. you provide a question here, and it's answered by answers that follow it.. Comments are just comments on the question & not additional detail (*those belong in the question itself*)... ie. I was attempting to aid in how this and Q&A sites work (alas maybe not in the best way).  All details belong in your question being my last *point*.   *Answers will not be to comments, but only to question itself; comments are not intended for replies from OP or Original Poster; they're just comments on the question*